# Custom logger not overwriting root log level

Tags: python, logging, python-logging

I'm trying to create a custom logger that should log at INFO level. The code looks as follows:

```py
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

# write to stderr
handler = logging.StreamHandler()
handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)

# format log message
formatter = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s: %(levelname)s:%(name)s - %(message)s")
handler.setFormatter(formatter)

logger.addHandler(handler)

logger.debug("This is a debug message")
logger.info("This is an info message")
logger.warning("This is a warning message")
logger.error("This is an error message")
logger.critical("This is a critical message")
```

The resulting output is:

```sh
2021-07-20 15:24:51,148: WARNING:__main__ - This is a warning message
2021-07-20 15:24:51,149: ERROR:__main__ - This is an error message
2021-07-20 15:24:51,149: CRITICAL:__main__ - This is a critical message
```

I expected the output to include logs at info level as well but as you can see it's not. However, if I change to `handler.setLevel(logging.ERROR)` the output looks like this:

```sh
2021-07-20 15:27:49,864: ERROR:__main__ - This is an error message
2021-07-20 15:27:49,864: CRITICAL:__main__ - This is a critical message
```

So if I am being more restrictive than the root logger it overwrites but if I am less restrictive it does not. How do I make the custom logger to log INFO-level logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the log level on the logger instance like this:

```py
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
# write to stderr
handler = logging.StreamHandler()
handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

# format log message
formatter = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s: %(levelname)s:%(name)s - %(message)s")
handler.setFormatter(formatter)


logger.addHandler(handler)

logger.debug("This is a debug message")
logger.info("This is an info message")
logger.warning("This is a warning message")
logger.error("This is an error message")
logger.critical("This is a critical message")
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so lee-pai-long's answer fixed it but I read up some more and I now understand why it works like it does.

The logger itself has a logging level which is set by

```py
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
```

The logger can have one or more handlers connected to it, each of which can have its own logging level.

```py
handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
```

For example you could have a FileHandler logging at WARNING-level and a StreamHandler logging at INFO-level.

So what caused the bug was that the handler was set to INFO but the logger's level was never set, making it default to the root level which is WARNING.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of additions to the existing answers:

1. For simple logging configuration like this, use
   [`logging.basicConfig`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig) as described in [this example](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#changing-the-format-of-displayed-messages) in Python
   documentation. It automatically logging levels for the root logger and
   its handlers.

   ```
   logging.basicConfig(format='%(levelname)s:%(message)s', level=logging.DEBUG)
   ```
2. To investigate the state of whole logging logger tree (and their
   handlers, formatter and filters) use [`logging_tree`](https://pypi.org/project/logging_tree/). If I add this
   in the end of the snippet in the question.

   ```
   import logging_tree

   logging_tree.printout()
   ```

   It makes very clear that's going on. It's especially helpful in more
   complex `logging` configurations.

   ```
   <--""
      Level WARNING
      |
      o<--"__main__"
          Level NOTSET so inherits level WARNING
          Handler Stream <_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stderr>' mode='w' encoding='utf-8'>
            Level INFO
            Formatter fmt='%(asctime)s: %(levelname)s:%(name)s - %(message)s' datefmt=None
   ```